# Models on the Rails Console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a simple class under the models folder like so:

```
class CaffeineShops
 def initialize
 end
end
```

When I run rails console and try CaffeineShops.new(), I get a message: "NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for CaffeineShops::Module"

I am using Rails 4.1.

Any ideas why I am getting that error?

Comment: Rails 4.1.6, unable to reproduce, this **does** work on a clean app and produces an empty instance. So, we might need more info than that, however, I'm not sure where to look... I thought of some name collision. Don't you have, by chance, anything else named `CaffeineShops`?

Comment: None of the answers below really address my question.

Comment: Do you have a module named `CaffeineShops` somewhere in you code base. Possibly even wrapping this class? It seems like a name spacing issue where you have a class and a module named the same which creates ambiguity and can cause many errors.

Comment: Nope. I literally just created a new application again and pasted that in. Same error.

Comment: This is interesting. Because it works for me. Copy-pasted to be sure, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/63iwPKp.png Seems like it needs some research... I dunno. Dependencies? Ruby version (that's unlikely, but who knows)? Restarting rails console?

Comment: You might try digging in using `pry` instead of `irb` that allows for navigation around your classes and methods with commands like `cd` and `ls`. Just suggesting options...

Comment: What is the name of your new Application. It wouldn't happen to be `caffeine_shops` would it? If it is this is where the module was created. A module is created with the name of your application and is utilized in many files. Take a look at `config/application.rb` to confirm.

Comment: Yep. That was it. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: No problem the error would have been far more obvious if you generated models because then it would actually raise an error glad it worked out.

Comment: @engineersmnky now you get the honor of making it an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot name a model the same name as the application itself. When you run `rails g caffeine_shops` this creates a module named `CaffeineShops` which will power your application.

The module is utilized in many files including

> config\application.rb
>
> config\environment.rb
>
> config\environments\development.rb
>
> config\environments\production.rb
>
> config\environments\test.rb
>
> config\initializers\secret_token.rb
>
> config\initializers\session_store.rb
>
> config\routes.rb
>
> config.ru *actually starts the application on Rack-based servers
>
> Rakefile  *loads rake tasks for the application

When you then try to name a class the same name it creates ambiguity in the rails application so your code is assuming you mean the `module CaffeineShops` not the `class CaffeineShops`.

If you were to actually use a generator to define this model rails would make it very clear there was a problem with this e.g.

```
rails g caffeine_shops
cd caffeine_shops
rails g model caffeine_shops 
#=>The name 'CaffeineShops' is either already used in your application or reserved
   by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```